# Cucumber - implementing missing steps in java

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

I have the below cucumber feature without any corresponding java code actions.

```
@CucumberTest
Scenario: Testing cucumber
 Given I have this test.
 When I test This
 Then I get this
```

When I run it I get the following results

```
    1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
    3 Steps (3 undefined)
    0m0.000s


    You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

    Given("^I have this test\\.$", () -> {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    });

    When("^I test This$", () -> {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    });

    Then("^I get this$", () -> {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    });
```

But I want the missing steps to be in java like the following :

```
    @Given("^I have this test\\.$")
    public void I_have_this_test() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }
```

Can anyone help me how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Can you give some details as to why the last code snippet you are posting is not working? This is just a case of: Cucumber has recommended you to use lambda expressions (a new feature introduced in Java 8) but you want to do it with traditional Java methods, which is also fine.

Comment: What command are you using? Seems like the ruby cucumber is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting code snippets for Java 8. Please share your dependencies with us.

I would assume that you have a dependency to (using Maven style dependencies)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Instead, I think you would like to depend on

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Update your question with your dependencies from your build tool and we might be able to help you more.

Comment: Thanks. I changed "cucumber-java8" to "cucumber-java" and it worked fine.