# Stepdefs are not recognized when running but they are recognized when I hover over the steps in .feature file why?

Tags: java, maven, cucumber-jvm

I have viewed the following similar questions and they are not applicable:
[Cucumber - implementing missing steps in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300494/cucumber-implementing-missing-steps-in-java)

[cucumber not able to recognize the implemented methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575235/cucumber-not-able-to-recognize-the-implemented-methods)

also viewed https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues but no hits

I am running Java 1.8 with cucumber, when I hover over the steps in .feature file i can see there implementation but when i run the test i get:

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

```
@Given("^I am on the Login Page$")
public void i_am_on_the_Login_Page() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^I enter the non existent email$")
public void i_enter_the_non_existent_email() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^I enter the false password$")
public void i_enter_the_false_password() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^I click on it$")
public void i_click_on_it() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^I still on the page$")
public void i_still_on_the_page() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

I thought may be i did some thing wrong in project configurations but when I also imported the cucumber-java-skeleton from https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

when I populate the skelton project with my own implementation as below i get the above same error when i run the test but i still can see the implementation when i hover over steps in .feature file:

```
@Given("^I am on the Login Page$")
public void i_am_on_the_Login_Page() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

}

@When("^I enter the non existent email$")
public void i_enter_the_non_existent_email() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

}

@When("^I enter the false password$")
public void i_enter_the_false_password() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

}

@When("^I click on it$")
public void i_click_on_it() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
}

@Then("^I still on the page$")
public void i_still_on_the_bb() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

}
```

.feature file:

```
 Feature: Login 


  Scenario: Testing with false credentials
    Given I am on the Login Page 
    When I enter the non existent email 
    And I enter the false password 
    And I click on it
    Then I still on the page
```

I am using Netbeans latest version with the same pom.xml file as the skelton project.

I have used tidy Gherkin to get the Gherkin translate into Java code

is there any other way to get Gherkin translated into Java specially Java 8 other than Tidy gherkin?? maybe that is the issue??

Thank you for you help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am away from my computer so I don't have a way to check this, but have your Gherkin match you method names exactly.

Comment: not exactly, for example: Gherkin "I click on it" >> method name "i_click_on_it() ", i got it translated from Gherkin to Java by Tidy Gherkin, is there any other way to transform Gherkin into java Methods, if tidy Gherkin is not 100% reliable?, as far as i know you can change the method name you get from gherkin and the test should run fine, so it can not be because of method name mismatch with gherkin, as far as I know

Comment: What does your runner file look like, and can you paste the error message here?

Comment: I tried this:

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty"})
public class RunCukesTest {
} and also tried:
     @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
 @CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty"}, strict = true, monochrome = true 
     
 ,features = "path/to/.feature/file"

 )

 public class RunCukesTest {
        
 }

Comment: the error i get: Running skeleton.RunCukesTest
Feature: Login

  Scenario: Testing with false credentials # skeleton/belly.feature:4
    Given I am on the Login Page
    When I enter the non existent email
    And I enter the false password
    And I click on it
    Then I still on the page, 1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
5 Steps (5 undefined)
0m0.000s

Comment: as per your runner class, you are missing the glue path in runner class, please add glue path. for example, glue = { "skeleton"}

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I solved it by creating folder "must be folder not Package" under the Test packages directory, that will contain the .feature files, and then i created also another Package under the Test packages, that contains the stepdefs and the other classes, in eclipse it worked even if i did not specify the features and glue options in the runner but in netbeans you should specify the features option, otherwise it will not recognize the features file and will give you "no tests found", but in Netbeans still no need to specify the glue option, if you followed the above steps